# Add Radiobutton to RadioGroup, RadioButton is an item from another Activity

Tags: java, android-activity, radio-button, radio-group, android-studio-2.3

Im trying to put automatically generated radio buttons into a radio group and trying format them. I have an extra activity with one radio button where i can format the single radio button. I cant find another way to change the `app:buttonTint="@android:color/holo_green_light"`from the xml. 
Here my example code:

```
1: Radiogroup group;

2. group = (RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.radiogroup);

3: LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

4: final View item = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.testactivity, null);

5: RadioButton addradiobutton = (RadioButton)item.findViewbyId(R.id.rb_from_other_activity);

6: group.addView(addradiobutton);
```

The programm crashes at line 6. Im not sure but i guess `addradiobutton` isn't a "real" RadioButton.

Here is the Fatal Exception at line 6:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{de.user.name.app/de.user.project.app.activity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first....
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
```

Comment: Could you add to the question the full stack trace you get on line 5? That way we can tell what the error is about

Comment: Additionally, please read how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also take the time to go through the [welcome tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to know your way around here (and also to earn your first badge). Cheers

Comment: Thanks for the advice! Hope its better now.

Comment: I believe you are not instantiating `group`, and later calling `addView()`

Comment: i initialized group, sorry. It does work when i delete line 2,3 and 4 and instead use `addradiobutton = new RadioButton(this);` but now i cant format that radio button